# Display all videos from JSON (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have code for AJAX to get Links from table

Here is code

```
 <script>
  $('#display').click(function() {
    var vacancyId = $("#vacancy").val();
    var model = {
      vacancyId: vacancyId
    };

    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("Links", "Questions")',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      data: JSON.stringify(model),
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
        var question2 = data[0];
        var videoHTML = '<video width="320" height="240" style="margin-left: 130px;margin-top: 20px;" controls>';
        videoHTML += '<source src="' + document.location.origin + "/uploads/" + question2.Linkes + ".webm" + '" type="video/webm">';
        videoHTML += '</video>';
        $(".videolist").append(videoHTML);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Now I display only first video in array, but It can be about 10, I need to display all ten videos, how I need to rewrite code?

Comment: Wrap it in a for loop over `data`

Comment: Smth like this `for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) `?@Andrei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your success function should be like this.

Post your Json sample data for accurate solution.

```
success: function(data) {
  var question2 = data;
  for (var i = 0; i <= question2.length-1; i++) {
    var videoHTML = '<video width="320" height="240" style="margin-left: 130px;margin-top: 20px;" controls>';
    videoHTML += '<source src="' + document.location.origin + "/uploads/" + question2[i].Linkes + ".webm" + '" type="video/webm">';
    videoHTML += '</video>';
    $(".videolist").append(videoHTML);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have one problem , for link it gets `undefined`

Comment: can you share your sample Json data

Comment: [{ID: 3, Linkes: "130227898"}, {ID: 4, Linkes: "155137192"}, {ID: 5, Linkes: "171006755"},…]

Comment: glad about that